# Switch in a tableview with UserDefaults, several is activated by itself

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsuserdefaults, uiswitch

I have a problem, I explain.

I want to activate a Switch and it is possible to open the application in a tableView.

For this I save the label in an NSUserDefault and if a the opening of the application the label is in the NSUserDefailt it activates the switch.

The problem is that on the following pictures I just switch on switch A and B but when I scrool other switch activates as q, s, c but never the same.

Do you have an idea to suggest me? 
I but my code below with the console.

[Screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Djcbo.png)

[Screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aB0Wr.png)

**ViewController :**

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView_t: UITableView!

let station = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","&","é","("]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as? TableViewCell

    cell?.configCell(station[indexPath.item])

    return cell!
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return station.count
}
```

**TableViewCell :**

```
@IBOutlet weak var switch_t: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var label_t: UILabel!

func configCell(_ labels : String)
{
    label_t.text = labels

    if let sav = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "switch") as? [String]
    {
        print(sav)
        for switchs in sav
        {
            print(switchs)
            if switchs == labels
            {
                switch_t.setOn(true, animated: false)
                print("On")
            }
        }
     }
}

@IBAction func actionSwitch(_ sender: Any)
{
    var sav : [String] = []

    if let saving = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "switch") as? [String]
    {
        sav = saving
    }

    if switch_t.isOn
    {
        sav.append(label_t.text!)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(sav, forKey: "switch")
        print(sav)
    }
    else
    {
        var number = 0

        for s in sav
        {
            if s == label_t.text
            {
                sav.remove(at: number)
                UserDefaults.standard.set(sav, forKey: "switch")
            }
            number += 1
            print(sav)
        }
    }

}
```

**Console :**

> ["A", "B"]
>   A
>   On
>   B
>   ["A", "B"]
>   A
>   B
>   On
>   ["A", "B"]
>   A
>   B
>   ["A", "B"]
>   A
>   B
>   ["A", "B"]
>   A
>   B
>   ["A", "B"]
>   A
>   B
>   ["A", "B"]
>   A
>   B
>   ["A", "B"]
>   A
>   B
>   ["A", "B"]
>   A
>   B
>   ["A", "B"]
>   A
>   B
>   ["A", "B"]
>   A
>   B
>   ["A", "B"]
>   A
>   B
>   ["A", "B"]
>   A
>   B
>   ["A", "B"]
>   A
>   B
>   ["A", "B"]
>   A
>   B
>   ["A", "B"]
>   A
>   B

Comment: since cells are reused, you can try add `else {switch_t.setOff(true, animated: false)}`. Basically they remember their state when reused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cells get reused. You must always set a cell's properties for every condition to fully setup the cell for each index path. Your code only deals with turning a cell's switch on, but not off.

There are two solutions.

1. Update your `configCell` method to turn the switch off under any conditions it should not be turned on.
2. Override the cell's `prepareForReuse` method. In this method you should reset all state of the cell. This would include setting the switch to off and clearing the label's text.

On a side note, your code has several other minor issues that should be cleaned up.

1. Don't use key-value coding with `UserDefaults` unless you have a clearly understood need to do so. Use the proper methods to save and read values from `UserDefaults`.
2. In your `cellForRowAt` you should force-cast the cell to the desired type. This makes the rest of the code in that method easier to write and you want the app to crash quickly if the cast is wrong because it means you have a programming error that needs to be fixed.
3. Minor - the parameter to your `configCell` method is called `labels` but it only repents a single label. Giving it a plural name makes it confusing.
4. Your logic for checking if a cell's switch should be on or not is far more complicated than it needs to be. Use the `contains` method of `Array`.
5. Your code for updating `UserDefaults` is all more complicated than it needs to be.
6. You are referencing the `item` property of `IndexPath`. This is meant to be used with `UICollectionView`. For `UITableView`, use `row`.

Below is how I would write your code after fixing all of the above issues.

Table controller:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableViewCell

    cell.configCell(station[indexPath.row])

    return cell
}
```

Cell code:

```
func configCell(_ label: String) {
    label_t.text = label

    if let sav = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "switch") as? [String] {
        switch_t.isOn = sav.contains(label)
    } else {
        switch_t.isOn = false
    }
}

@IBAction func actionSwitch(_ sender: UISlider) {
    var labels = (UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "switch") as? [String]) ?? []

    if let text = label_t.text {
        if switch_t.isOn {
            labels.append(text)
        } else {
            if let index = labels.indexOf(text) {
                labels.remove(at: index)
            }
        }
        UserDefaults.standard.set(labels, forKey: "switch")
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, Your comment helps me a lot. I will correct any problems you have brought me. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Because you never set the switch off when the labels not in the UserDefault. Please try

```
switch_t.setOn(false, animated: false)
```

in proper place.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make clear the iOS doesnt create new Cell for every Row, it just reuses 1 Cell again and again , Make sure your switch is On or Off before displaying next cell other wise same state would be applied to other.. in your case you never turn off the switch when cell was about to display

```
switch_t.setOn(false, animated: true)
```